# Differentiating $F(x\mid Y=y)$ with respect to $y$

Tags: random-variables, conditional-probability

I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ that are jointly distributed with a distribution $F$ and affiliated to each other: $f(x,y)f(x',y')\geqslant f(x',y)f(x,y')$ for all $x,y$.

I get that this implies that higher $x$ is more likely among higher $y$'s and also vice versa.

Does this mean $F(x\mid Y=y)$ is convex in $y$ for any given $x$?

Comment: I named my question this way cos the main question in my mind was about the second derivatives of $F(x|Y=y)$ wrt $y$. Sorry for any potential confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if $Y\sim\operatorname N(0,1)$ and $X\mid Y\sim\operatorname N(Y,1)$? Then a higher $X$ is more probable among higher values of $Y$ and vice-versa (and here I'm using capital letters, for a reason, unlike what I see in the question), and
\begin{align}
& F(x\mid Y=y) = \Phi(x-y), \\[8pt]
\text{and so } & \frac{d^2}{dy^2} F(x\mid Y=y) = -\frac d {dy} \varphi(x-y) \\[8pt]
= {} & \varphi(x-y) \cdot y = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \cdot e^{-(x-y)^2/2} \cdot y
\end{align}
and the sign of this depends on the sign of $y.$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can I take that by your example it means that we cannot have a general statement on the sign of the second derivatives as it depends on the actual form of F and also the ranges of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @achung17 : Probably.